# C++ array pointers [] or ++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

lets say I want to iterate through an array of doubles and sum them. I have two ways to do this.

A)

```
double sum (double * series, int size) {
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        sum += *series++;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

B)

```
double sum (double * series, int size) {
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        sum += series[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

which is better and why / when should I use one over the other.

Comment: I like B) because it's shorter and easier to understand if you don't know how pointers work. You can use vectors with std::accumulate too.

Comment: Style A isn't as clear to me what you are accomplishing. Personally, I always choose style B, coming from a C# background.

Comment: @Richard J. Ross III, `*series` evaluates to the data contained in what series is pointing to. The loop increments series so it points to the next element in the array each time.

Comment: @chris I understand what is happening, but it requires a double-take for me, as I said, I just find B easier to read.

Comment: There's no point in final decrement of `series` in example (A).  Modifications to the parameter do not affect the value in the parent, because C is a call-by-value language.

Comment: @Richard J. Ross III, Ah, better safe than sorry :) I very much agree with the readability point though.

Comment: Oh, out of all my ignorance, I just noticed this is C, not C++. The vectors would be a good choice if it were C++, but they won't work in C.

Comment: @chris: It was C++, but then someone edited the tags.  I'm going to roll that back...

Comment: btw. sum needs initialising - I'll fix that.

Comment: There's some unnecessary stuff in A... I'm going to change it. That said, I would use B over A, but `return std::accumulate(series,series+size,0.0)` over either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a question of readability, it should not affect performance. I think B is the most readable, and therefore preferable.

I could also propose a third variant, which is range-based (note the `begin` and `end` parameters):

```
double sum (double* begin, double* end) {
    double sum = 0.;
    for (double* it = begin; it != end; ++it) {
        sum += *it;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

This is idiomatic C++ in many cases and generalizes more easily. That is not to say that it is *always* preferable, it is just another variant in a question about readability and maintainability.

Comment: Yeah, this is basically what std::accumulate does with vectors.

Comment: Let’s hope that `begin` `<` `end`. What happens if `begin` `==` `end`?

Comment: @SimonWright: Then it won't enter the loop, and return 0 right away. The loop condition is checked before entering the body :)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I was forgetting that `end` is 1 past the end.

Answer (score 5):

I would chose style B as well, but then you should prefer standard algorithms over explicit loops:

```
#include <numeric>

double sum(const double* const series, const int size) {
    return std::accumulate(series, series + size, 0.0);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Neither is inherently better than the other; you should choose whichever makes the intention of your code clearest.  With any modern compiler, they should be optimised to identical machine code.

---

*Note, however, that passing around raw pointers to raw arrays is considered bad style in C++.  Consider using a container class such as `std::vector`.*

Answer (score 1):

In terms of performance there should be no difference when you use modern optimizing compiles.

Back in 1978, the first way was somewhat faster on PDP-11, because indirect autoincrement addressing required fewer cycles to process, and there was no optimizers capable of converting index+offset to autoincrement.

P.S. Setting `series -= size;` has no effect, because `series` is passed by value.

Comment: series -= size; sets the series to point back to first item right?

Comment: @PatrickLorio Yes, but it does it on the *copy* of the pointer, which is passed by value. Since you are returning on the next line without accessing `series` after the assignment, this assignment has no effect. It would make sense if you were to use that pointer *again*, for example to find the largest or smallest element in addition to finding the sum.

Comment: @PatrickLorio It doesn't matter. Because the actual pointer passed in is passed by value, when you `-=` the size it doesn't effect the variable that was passed in initially.

Comment: Yes, but it's not needed.  Why do you think it is?  [Sorry, I just missed the two previous comments saying exactly this, but I can't delete the comment.  --Dale]

Comment: @DaleHagglund new to C++ from java/C#, just didn't know.

Answer (score 0):

The C++11 way to iterate the array (if you don't want to just sum them and that accumulate doesn't fit your need) is:

```
double sum (const double * series, int size) { 
    double sum = 0.0; 
    for_each (series, series + size, [&](double v) { 
        sum += v;
    });
    return sum; 
}
```

Note that if you used a vector or a list you'd get pretty much the same code:

```
double sum (const vector<double>& series) { 
    double sum = 0.0; 
    for_each (begin(series), end(series), [&](double v) { 
        sum += v;
    });
    return sum; 
}
```